# No authorization exception thrown when accessing nested resources with devise & cancan

Tags: authentication, devise, authorization, cancan

I use devise for authentication and cancan to handle authorization and I am trying to do something I think is simple: I want to make sure a book's author can only edit his books.

So, I have the following `routes.rb`:

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books
end
```

and `ability.rb`:

```
class AuthorAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, Book, author_id: user.id
  end
end
```

The problem I am encountering is that, if I try to edit another author's book, I would expect Cancan to throw an Unauthorized exception. It is not! and all I get is an error as follow:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /api/authors/2/books/1
====================================================

> Couldn't find Book with id=1 [WHERE "books"."author_id" = 4]

(gem) activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 341
```

Note that, while my route suggest I am author with id=2, devise says I am really author with id=4 (from my auth_token). Should it throws the exception since I am not this book's author (hence the active record exception)?

Has anyone encountered such a use case and solved it successfully?

---

A friend of mine pointed that I might be not properly authorizing the resource properly, so here is what I have:

```
class Api::BooksController < Api::ApiController
  load_and_authorize_resource :book, :through => :current_api_user
```

After he pointed that Cancan is in fact fetching the record through the :current_api_user scope (hence it is not finding the book in the first place) BEFORE performing authorization. Which causes the issue here.

Once I removed the `:through` option, I got the right exception... Now I have:

```
class Api::BooksController < Api::ApiController
      load_and_authorize_resource :book
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: More digging onto this: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/43

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189018/recordnotfound-raised-when-using-find-by-id-to-get-non-existent-record-in-rspec

Comment: This "Once I removed the :through option, I got the right exception" makes it sound like you have answered your own question.  Is that correct?  If so, please consider writing an Answer to this Question.